# Definition of $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have found several discussion of the definition of $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267972/condition-for-u-in-ck-omega-to-be-extendable-to-u-in-ck-overline-omega?rq=1) ,but I am still confused.

For simplicity, let us assume $\Omega$ is a bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $0 \le k \le \infty$ is an integer.

Consider the following three conditions for functions:

(1) $\text{for all } |\alpha| \le k, \partial^\alpha f 
   \text{ has a continuous extension to $\overline{\Omega}$ } . $

(2) $\text{for all } |\alpha| \le k, \partial^\alpha f 
   \text{ is uniformly continuous on } \Omega . $

(3) $\exists \tilde{f} \in C^k(U), U \text{ open and } U  \supset \overline{\Omega}, \text{ such that} \tilde{f}|_\Omega = f  . $

I have known that $(3) \Longrightarrow (1) \iff (2)$, and I believe (and have seen elsewhere, for example the link above) that $(1) \Longrightarrow (3)$. But I don't understand how to prove.

In the link above, Gio67 suggests that one may use the Whitney extension theorem. To apply the theorem, for a function $f$ satisfy (1) and a boundary point $x \in \partial \Omega$, one should check that
$$ \lim_{y \to x} \dfrac{f(y)-\sum_{|\beta|\le k} \dfrac{ \partial^\beta f(x)}{\beta !}(x-y)^\beta}{|x-y|^k} = 0 $$
(And some other condition) But I don't know why.

Comment: If the remainder is written in integral form then the compatibility condition seems to be fulfilled due to uniform continuity of the derivatives. Do I miss something here?

Comment: You are absolutely right!